# Slow performance of Row_Number with multiple columns in partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, indexing

I am trying to improve the performance of a query that uses Row_Number and Dense_Rank. The data I am working with is rather large (40+ million rows up to 100 million rows). While Row_Number and Dense_Rank normally are very efficient on smaller sets of data my query can run between 30 minutes to an hour.

I have applied an order by on the #Test table and an index which has improved the performance, but even with the performance improves it can still run 15+ minutes. I have also attempted to add additional indexes to no avail.

Additionally, I have attempted to convert the #Test table to a CTE, but it did not seem to improve the performance much.

Below is the my code along with the index and order by that I have added. Am I applying the right index for performance? Do I need to include/exclude fields in the index or change the order? Other than changing the index is there anything else that I could do to improve performance?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TEST') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEST

select f.*
 into #TEST
 From (SELECT Cl.Field1
    , Cl.Field2
    , Cl.Field3
    , Cl.Field4
    , Cl.Field5
    , Cl.Field6
    , Cl.Field7
    , Cl.Field8
    , Cl.Field9
    , Serv.Field10
    , Serv.Field11
    , Serv.Field12
    , Cl.Field13
    , Cl.Field14    
    , Cl.Field15
    , sum(serv.Field16) as Field16
    , Serv.Field17
    , Serv.Field18

    FROM #Cl Cl
        INNER JOIN #Cl_Line L on Cl.Id = L.Id
        INNER JOIN #Serv Serv ON  Cl.Id = Serv.Id AND L.L_Nbr = Serv.L_Nbr

Group by Cl.Field1
    , Cl.Field2
    , Cl.Field3
    , Cl.Field4
    , Cl.Field5
    , Cl.Field6
    , Cl.Field7
    , Cl.Field8
    , Cl.Field9
    , Serv.Field10
    , Serv.Field11
    , Serv.Field12
    , Cl.Field13
    , Cl.Field14
    , Cl.Field15
    , Serv.Field17
    , Serv.Field18

) f
order by Field17, Field16 DESC, Field18

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Cl ON #TEST (Field2, Field3, Field6, Field7, Field5, Field4, Field8, Field9, Field11,
            Field12, Field14, Field15, Field10, Field17, Field18, Field16 DESC)
            INCLUDE (Field1, Field13)


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Cl_TEST') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Cl_TEST;

select c.*
 into #Cl_TEST
 From (select Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6, Field7, Field8
    , Field9, Field10, Field11, Field12, Field13, Field14, Field15
    , Field16, Field17, Field18
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Field2, Field3, Field6, Field7, Field5, Field4, Field8, Field9, Field11,
            Field12, Field14, Field15, Field10, Field17) 
            AS ERowGroup
    , row_number() over (partition by Field2, Field3, Field6, Field7, Field5, Field4, Field8, Field9, Field11,
            Field12, Field14, Field15, Field10, Field17 Order by Field17, Field16 desc) 
            AS ERow_Numbers
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Field2, Field3, Field6, Field7, Field5, Field4, Field8, Field9, Field11,
            Field12, Field14, Field15, Field10, Field18) 
            AS PRowGroup
    , row_number() over (partition by Field2, Field3, Field6, Field7, Field5, Field4, Field8, Field9, Field11,
            Field12, Field14, Field15, Field10, Field18 Order by Field18) 
            AS PRow_Numbers

FROM #TEST

) c

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Cl_Cx ON #Cl_Test (ERowGroup, PRowGroup)
```

Comment: How big these tables are?
Can you run each query separately and find out which one takes more time.

Comment: The tables are big. The #TEST table takes a few minutes. The #Cl_TEST table is what is taking 80% of the time.

Comment: How many records in #Cl_TEST?

Comment: Both #TEST and #Cl_TEST have approximately 42 million records.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: I am using SSMS 2016.

Comment: After doing some additional testing and looking at the query statistics it looks like the performance bottleneck is the partition by being used in the two row_number functions.

Comment: The only suggestion I was going to make was to try a columnstore index. In my testing it makes some improvements on transaction duration and cpu time, though maybe not enough to warrant the time taken to build the index. If you're only playing around with temp tables, I would try a clustered columnstore index, so as not to have to build more structures. You would need to drop any rowstore clustered index first, and you would need to ensure the temp tables don't have a lot of updates/deletes happening to be viable.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, query is poorly written.So there is no point in any kind of Index startegy.

It need complete query rewrite.For this we need to know requirement,main tables schema along with their data type.

Why you need to group bY in all columns, then again using window function in as much column ?

By looking at your query there may one improvment.

Comment `Row_Number` from first place.

Then in another query do `row_number()` in `ERowGroup` and `PRowGroup`